# Updating a dataset and displaying it back to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-update, refresh, oledbdataadapter

I found a way on MDSN to update a dataset and display it back to the datagridview. Almost like refreshing the datagridview. However I'm hoping to find a way to do this with an oledpdataadapter. Here is the code I found below to fill the datagridview with the updated contents, there has to be a way to do this same thing with the oledbdataadapter.

```
 this.rscan_queueTableAdapter.Fill(this.rscanDataSet.rscan_queue);
 dgv_queue.refresh();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.aspx) are the properties and methods of the OleDbDataAdapter Class.

You may be able to do something like this:

```
 Public NotInheritable Class OleDbDataAdapter
 AcceptChangesDuringFill.Fill(this.rscanDataSet.rscan_queue);  
`dgv_queue.refresh();`
 end Class
```